# How to remove environment variable from ld.config in Solaris

Tags: environment-variables, solaris, ld, solaris-10

I have just added permanent environment variable to /var/ld/ld.config and /var/ld/64/ld.config using **crle** command:

```
crle -E VAR=VALUE -u
crle -E VAR=VALUE -u -64
```

How can I remove only this variable from ld.config, but leave rest params?

Answer (score 1):

crle lets you add to an existing config file with -u, but it doesn't give you a way to selectively remove things from one. This is not symmetrical, and it's true that the ability to remove selected attributes might be considered to be missing functionality. However, note that crle config files are not expected to be manipulated in this way very often, so it's not a common use case to do this. Far more common is to create one, and then later to simply remove it entirely. And it must be said that config files in general are rarely used.

It's pretty easy to work around this. The goal is to remove an attribute, without having to remember all the other ones, simply carrying them over. Notice that the information displayed by crle for a given config file shows you the command that would recreate the file. You can therefore approximate the sort of selective removal you're after here, by using cut/paste to grab that displayed command, minus the part you no longer want.

For instance, let's create a config file with 2 environment variables:

```
% crle -c ld.config -E VAR1=v1 -E VAR2=v2
```

Later, if I want to remove VAR1 from the existing config file, I
would use 'crle -c file' to display the current contents:

```
% crle -c ld.config

Configuration file [version 5]: ld.config
    Platform:   32-bit LSB 80386
    Default Library Path:       /lib:/usr/lib  (system default)
    Trusted Directories:        /lib/secure:/usr/lib/secure  (system default)

Environment Variables:
    VAR1=v1  (permanent)
    VAR2=v2  (permanent)

Command line:
    crle -c ld.config -E VAR1=v1 -E VAR2=v2
```

That last line shows me all I need, to reproduce the config file, omitting the bit I no longer want:

```
% crle -c ld.config -E VAR2=v2
```